# django reverse lookup in model method

Tags: python, django, django-models

Google has lots of examples of doing reverse lookup in the interactive prompt but none of doing them inside a django model as a method.

I have the following models.py file:

```
class Client(models.Model):
    ...

    def __unicode__(self):
        return ???

class ClientDetails(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, null=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True)
    name_title = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=NAME_TITLE_CHOICES)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    ...
```

How do I get the client method to return last_name from ClientDetails?

Comment: There are multiple details per Client (that's the way an FK works).  Which ClientDetails in the `clientdetails_set` do you want?

Comment: I want to reference last_name

Comment: Yes.  you want last_name.  Which last_name?  The `clientdetails_set` will have more than 1 row in it.  When there are 2 (or more) rows, which row has the proper last_name value?

Comment: apperently what I am looking for is `self.clientdetails_set.all().order_by('-created')[0].last_name`

Comment: `self.clientdetails_set.all().order_by('-created')[0]` can be written as: `self.clientdetails_set.latest('created')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a ClientDetails object should only ever be associated with a single Client object, then I would change your FK to a OneToOneField, which will provide you with a neat reverse accessor that can only ever link between a given Client and its associated ClientDetails. Then you can do:

```
try:
   return self.clientdetails.last_name
except ClientDetails.DoesNotExist:
   ##handle it here, returning a graceful message
```

Alternatively, if you kept it as a FK, then you'd have to do something like:

```
try:
    self.clientdetails_set.all()[0].last_name
except IndexError, e:
    ## handle exception here
```

but using a FK here is brittle and not great form (as the exception-handling implies: if there is none returned, then you'll get an IndexError. Also, there might be more than one ClientDetails object linked to that Client, and you'd only get the details of the first one here.)

So, I really would recommend using a OneToOneField instead of that FK. (All a OneToOneField is basically an FK with `unique=True` set on it and some neater accessors than standard FKs)

Comment: as you can see I have updated the clientDetails model to include a time stamp so I can have a history of when and by whom the details where changed. Therefor I am looking to retrieve the latest version of clientDetails, and the last_name from that version (if that makes sense)

Comment: In that case, you want self.clientdetails_set.all().order_by('-created')[0].last_name

Comment: Also, did you know there's an auto_now attribute possible on models.DateTimeField? Check out http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#datetimefield

Comment: Cheers Steve! just what I was looking for! If it wasn't for this site I never know how I would have found that out. Any chance you can break down that line for us (just the '_set' bit and why you need 'all()')

Comment: You're welcome. Sounds like you could do with reading up more from the core docs http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ and also reading your way through the (free, online) Django Book at http://djangobook.com/en/2.0/ which explains what you're after and more. Specifically, check out the sections on model relations and querysets

Answer (score 3):

For that you can use in client the *clientdetails_set* to access all the ClientDetails objects that are linked to that client.

The set is an object set from Django, so calling the method **all()** will retrieve every of the objects. If you know there's only one you can do **self.clientdetails_set.all()[0].last_name**

Here's the link for the django documentation: [Link](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/)

Comment: You forgot this: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward in your answer.

Comment: Sorry... your right... Every time a change is made to the client details a new clientDetails is made with a more recent time stamp (created). So I will be wanting the one with the most recent time stamp, so therefore the most recent last_name